# How to convert following SQL query to Lambda expression?

Tags: linq, lambda

I have a following `SQL query` how can I convert to `lambda` expression

`select * from ContractItems 
  where ID in   (SELECT distinct contractItemId from ContractPackageItems 
  where contractPackageId in  (SELECT ID from ContractPackage
  where ContractID = 680))`

from the above query I need to know if row exist or not. If row exist then return true.

-TIA

---Update---
Here is what I got but it is not working

```
(from contractItem in _entities.ContractItems
 where contractItem.ID == (from contractPackageItems in _entities.ContractPackageItems
 where contractPackageItems.ContractPackageID ==  (from contractPackage in _entities.ContractPackages where contractPackage.ContractID == contractId select contractPackage.ID) select contractPackageItems.ContractItemId).Distinct()).Any();
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service. If you can show us what you've already tried, and explain what's happening vs what you want to happen, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this not do what you want?

```
var results = (from ci in _entities.contractItems
               join cpi in _entities.contractPackageItems on ci.ID equals cpi.contractItemId
               join cp in _entities.contractPackage on cpi.contractPackageId equals cp.ID
               where cp.ContractID = 680
               select ci).Any();
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. even the query is not what I am trying to get but it help me to get what I need.